# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor doesn't recognise task in DAG is on status SUCCESS

Tags: python, airflow

Got a test_dag_father looking like that:

```html
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
from airflow.utils.state import State

WORKFLOW_DAG_ID = "test_dag_father"

WORKFLOW_START_DATE = datetime(year=2020, month=4, day=27)

workflow_default_args = {
    "owner": "me",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": WORKFLOW_START_DATE,
    "email": [mail],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": True,
    "schedule_interval": "*/5 * * * *",
}

now = datetime.now()

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=WORKFLOW_DAG_ID,
    start_date=WORKFLOW_START_DATE,
    default_args=workflow_default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *",
)


t1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id="run_son_dag", trigger_dag_id="test_dag_son", dag=dag)

t2 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id="waiting_for_dag",
    external_dag_id="test_dag_son",
    external_task_id="special",
    check_existence=True,
    poke_interval=5,
    allowed_states=[State.SUCCESS, State.SKIPPED, State.FAILED, State.NONE],
    timeout=90,
    dag=dag,
)

t3 = BashOperator(task_id="echo3", bash_command='echo "Here is the message: 3"', dag=dag, retries=1,)


t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

and the dag that is operated called test_dag_son, which looks like this:

```html
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

WORKFLOW_DAG_ID = "test_dag_son"

WORKFLOW_START_DATE = datetime(year=2020, month=4, day=27)

workflow_default_args = {
    "owner": "me",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": WORKFLOW_START_DATE,
    "email": [mail],
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": True,
    "schedule_interval": None,
}


dag = DAG(dag_id=WORKFLOW_DAG_ID, start_date=WORKFLOW_START_DATE, default_args=workflow_default_args, catchup=False)



t1 = BashOperator(task_id="echo1", bash_command='echo "Here is the message: 1"', dag=dag, retries=1,)

t2 = BashOperator(task_id="special", bash_command='echo "Here is the message: 2"', dag=dag, retries=1,)


t1 >> t2
```

When running the test_dag_father I get on the ExternalTaskSensor this log:

```html
[2020-11-26 16:07:54,558] {{base_task_runner.py:133}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'test_dag_father', 'waiting_for_dag', **'2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00'**, '--job_id', '2435', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/DAGs/tests/test_dag_father.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpdif2n401']

[2020-11-26 16:07:56,216] {{external_task_sensor.py:113}} INFO - Poking for test_dag_son.special on **2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00** ... 
[2020-11-26 16:07:56,242] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 2435: Subtask waiting_for_dag [2020-11-26 16:07:56,241] {{dagbag.py:90}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/DAGs/tests/test_dag_son.py
[2020-11-26 16:08:01,302] {{external_task_sensor.py:113}} INFO - Poking for test_dag_son.special on 2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00 ... 
[2020-11-26 16:08:01,326] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 2435: Subtask waiting_for_dag [2020-11-26 16:08:01,326] {{dagbag.py:90}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/DAGs/tests/test_dag_son.py
[2020-11-26 16:08:06,381] {{external_task_sensor.py:113}} INFO - Poking for test_dag_son.special on 2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00 ... 
[2020-11-26 16:08:06,406] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 2435: Subtask waiting_for_dag [2020-11-26 16:08:06,405] {{dagbag.py:90}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/DAGs/tests/test_dag_son.py
[2020-11-26 16:08:11,492] {{external_task_sensor.py:113}} INFO - Poking for test_dag_son.special on 2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00 ... 
[2020-11-26 16:08:11,516] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 2435: Subtask waiting_for_dag [2020-11-26 16:08:11,516] {{dagbag.py:90}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/DAGs/tests/test_dag_son.py
[2020-11-26 16:08:16,576] {{external_task_sensor.py:113}} INFO - Poking for test_dag_son.special on 2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00 ... 
[2020-11-26 16:09:28,088] {{taskinstance.py:1047}} ERROR - Snap. Time is OUT.
```

The timeout is OK to be 90 seconds, as the test_dag_son is finishing within less than 30 seconds. I tried to use:

1. Adding *execution_delta* but this is not needed as the time for the both dags is the same (I bolded both in logs).
2. I ran the *test_dag_father* using schedule. The *test_dag_son* shouldn't have any schedule.
3. task *special* is finished successfully and has SUCCESS on the airflow UI.

I would be very thankful to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way both DAGs are running on the same schedule/execution date. When you trigger a DAG with the TriggerDagRunOperator, it's like triggering that DAG, test_dag_son manually. Which means, the execution date is equal to when your DAG is triggered.
However, the ExternalTaskSensor is checking for the task *special* on the execution date 2020-11-26T16:00:00+00:00 which will never be the case.
You can't even use execution_delta as the execution date given by the TriggerDagRunOperator will always be different.

There is a new version of the TriggerDagRunOperator allowing you to wait for your triggered DAG before executing the task. As such, no need to use the externalTaskSensor anymore.
I've made a video about it right there: https://youtu.be/8uKW0mPWmCk

Enjoy :)

Comment: In case i have a parent Dag that triggers child dags, using TriggerDagRunOperator and ExternalTaskSensor, it works, has a default waiting time of 1 minute, in case i tried to use poke_interval, didn't work case i have schedule_interval to none, it is manually of triggered by events, i discovered that schedule_interval=None or doesn't poke with ext sensor, or poke is logged, but doesn't get the outcome of the child dag.